# How is web form content encoded in Safari's cache?

Tags: encoding, safari, character-encoding, browser-cache

A friend of mine just accidentally navigated off a web page where she entered a rather lengthy text into a web form. When navigating back to the page, the text was lost.

(Spoiler: The page had an auto-save feature and we were actually able to recover most of the text. Still I'm curious to find out whether it is possible to recover the text from the cache.)

She was using Safari and using `grep -r "[a rather unique word she remembered]" ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari` I was able to find the title of her text in the `com.apple.Safari/Cache.db`. Now it seems as if the text is also there, but possibly it needs to be converted into a different format.

Does anybody know how I can find out how to convert it to a readable format? Or is what I think is the text something completely different?

Below is the relevant part of the cache: "bibliotheken-mehr-als-ein-verstaubtes-buechergestell" is the title, the german sentence after the "wp_autosave" means that the text was autosaved at 10.27 (That's actually how we found out that it still must be on her account of the page) and I assume everything after the "IHDRÛ" on line 7 must be the text.

```
&lrm;<span id="edit-slug-buttons"><a href="#post_name" class="edit-slug button button-small hide-if-no-js" onclick="editPermalink(1844); return false;">Bearbeiten</a></span>
<span id="editable-post-name-full">bibliotheken-mehr-als-ein-verstaubtes-buechergestell</span>
<span id='view-post-btn'><a href='http://www.medienkompetenz-im-digitalen-zeitalter.ch/?p=1844' class='button button-small'>Beitrag ansehen</a></span>
Å>àø Ç~{"wp-refresh-post-lock":{"new_lock":"1402741629:62"},"wp_autosave":{"success":true,"message":"Entwurf wurde um 10:27:09 Uhr gespeichert."},"wp-auth-check":true,"server_time":1402741629}hàøÅR{"wp-refresh-post-lock":{"new_lock":"1402741644:62"},"wp-auth-check":true,"server_time":1402741644}Ü+àøåXâPNG


IHDRÛˇasBIT|dà›IDAT8ç}ìMlÜüŒÏœLw∑€-•Ì‚¶;ÖÜ@"E\™ñz@ç.@§˛ )I„¡Ù‰≈{3=  $DM/*
    jå÷à‡°¶-ÑJ(›Ú≥Ï∂Ëvv¶vª3Ì˛çlå,º«7Ô˜‰KﬁÔ©†æææw#ëàbYñ_”¥T•Ãø*ô≈b—€››˝√Y”4M$Á{{{7U V˝ﬂ–4ÌœEÀzÛÍ’+ÃÃLS(˚˝(-Î»f∆∫tµøè«≥\˚›ªü§Qi«_SãUvRX\ ˝xÑ\F≈F0˚˚˚=œÜÜÜbS±âuãv¬ä-¯ú  ‹MÃ":¿DÚÍ©‰m“˙||``  ;|Ïà[r›4O3_"ù+\Èe<9œ¬¢I›Ë ÒïQ6FPS…¿[ÌÈ±Îc7ß‰<bó$´˘À–QK6EIdÕ+~Í´ó¯‡˚£\iË@ùÀÒ`^f≠“L}∞˛‡rQl]r3eOÕ22£·ê™ÿ˚Ò7Ï˙Ú¶ª>cœˆ6B^ôyS £Îz+Ä¿ÎÛI.ó√ÄW>vn
†Ñ˝ú8Û.û£∞˙
oÕ"ô"sjñ›m>R©î¥ºA(RÛ˘≠·jÃ›‘r:_˝4 ÜÌ;±e≠©°∂±ñmJÄ¸Rûlv!Ωêey$õÕ±µEbXíÈ›Ë„«;3\÷„r\Kd÷T#‚Ê–Î
‹ãMa∆Ëk¨ÎÈÈ—?<}ä/¶™òú≥»xÍ %µÃ6B´ó∑óN∂îÿΩˇw∆«#@\|∞á<ıQ«ßáﬁ«„ÒqøËƒpÀ∂•I‚xcô}ÕáOúb‚ÓΩœÛ˘•oüªÎpsÛ˘ŒŒN˚∑_~∂≥∫jkF∆÷ü>µµøßÌKÉﬂŸØE£ˆ™¶¶Ø_˙¿‡LXQ⁄∂lﬁå€Ì&˘‰  •Ri<69˘…ú™^Æ0ÛBEÅˆó˛i*Û¥>∑QIENDÆB`Çáàøé(âPNG


IHDRÛˇasBIT|dàEIDAT8çM”Àk\UÄÒÔú{Ô<2ØNf&ìƒv£b¥A£A4ÿ¶u°v„F§vc≠HÍVƒE‘ÖP‘XàP\T–°h¥±§Bõî46â6MÛòf2ÈºÔ˚∏(Bø?‡∑˚ÑRJÒzÎ80Ã±ı˚«xÏ·©Ò¡Far`"÷ﬂ†E2◊åh€R¨ΩÁƒ˜áÂéÑRJÕ p>7˙¡…ß’F∫.]ÆP˘vÄıBô≥øÃ≤puÖ˝Ê≈ﬂK?¬«’sí∏˛@≤ÀÁ…Îﬂ>™çt%ª|l€c£ÊR®:XËD⁄Z⁄%<}˘ôSÖ»Ô∑ø ã)cØLhdIΩW¿¥|“œ73ﬁõ¢Æ"›¿ÌÏ‡¡vÜŒ˝„Áìmr¶Iıc“◊I\€«´K<v˜7≥ªøôGêØ∏8öÅ≠Ö85ì ›ù≈»ÑTÌ∑§ß›à˙ÄFe*l3Kzﬂ´ú˝Ω»⁄W7)ï=6W¯∫¡ÏÇM©‰rW_ä’ï S∫Ú„H€h;sË∆,F6ñã®Í-™´´xæ∆_W$aÈ!ì!˛∏·vÎ*ËÒAÛ∑∏x¶N·À∏A¿õ€ﬂ%<y]◊f€”Ë‹Vg[º»≠F€ru’Euk≈¡±=ª¬db>±º—2ÑÖ9Vf8ÚVµÜ€®±g˚uÿ*b/ÂâÑE]ÓâÛÛ˙Ç
@4!IÁ‹”‡t€ß¸ñ:¬›—2Êƒi<Waóx≠˜
÷˙õó6Èâ˚3…òY≤kWo#πæ—lÑZÕdˆoãÈ©MÜRCºbèÒıs§4ãÚ¸KãíL™„'°”¥∏"Œ_´{ªiX

À4ò˙≥≠1öDç\ãCggê:kãÍv∏º´ß„~°îRä'~ò'CZ†%˜@àXBÇéîË¬«1}\Saä∫Ù…ØõÊ¿yòÌ—€‡äóGß≈H:,3âÄN2Æ!§@©<œ°–PT-ÃÑ·º3p¬˚@ˇˇ*Ì3Ú{
ﬂ◊ÓÃ¶ùd“±2†ÄRÈ.ﬂµÔ˝o~µ˝9uÁçBà,êÓ{÷}Ìöx(¢â4 Jû∫πÏ©πIGMs@^)ï¯€ {ı˛zøIENDÆB`ÇÖjàøãVâPNG


IHDRÛˇasBIT|dàúIDAT8ç•í;hiÜüˇüôsôìâ&f≈†ÉocTÖ≥`ÏLcg•€lëbµmD0ÖïÿXEAm‘ ®†ª(´ETåpuwçûìèì8ìsôÀˇˇbÉïo˘¡˜ÚÚ¿F|{v˙{ƒj/ï€›Çg¥fvv.RQsÃY\Í<=˙ÊªÄ Ø[èzm≥ºÉ…Ÿh!¿àSdöa’c¢∞1Ï?xth »Ø;*7µ¨KéDÊìf`∫ï`RÖ€RÑ≥≠·ûÍãCÊ7ˇÁ®u°ÁˆGî‘ËF’
¬vÄ5Û
ï–qBúf∏9˚áeßN2⁄;Ø#Áó∞ÒÃÀ#ÖE¬ÙŸÀ<kÛë¬¢◊}çˇ~BvP()‹¢¶#ÕFËgPCπ®·‹K '^R;sÅ√œã‹∏5˛û√7äº[vèŒE3Ïì)Ñíe¿ Ÿ©‚Ò∂.ûmyõváo˘òXÕV∆µó=¨_ï«$∆8ÿÆÂÕæLY 4◊Ù“◊»òõ‘c!`.UDıà<–a ˚<üàÉ$R µ‡U◊}kÎ<û¸¿ƒL¿Î ‡a•∆Œﬁ)àC¿A ©œÿ—|›bÃîÿÅÑ¢nc¥våK{˜r˚n~Ÿ\§œÏBBhLÍí&π±y@ıE0¥¢ˇß ª
,iÒ_XÂD∏üï˝ÀâöÇ’µ?)v‘P %ãd‚2~ß{™ü=ò˛ªvo˜sécaêñƒëy¢4&nF_ÛîLïH.VÍ1U-o⁄˜‰‚WëÄâ´ˇˇµ§ÏÁÑëBåÜ ëÛ˛•KX4#’(1Y…
Ø⁄ÛœBïÁ≥eµ_ﬁΩrDI €+ÔHgÖwëå≤Lå=º‰
ÌΩˇf¡œè‰°;(~ÿL>‡IENDÆB`Ç∂   Ñ·»zıg%óZáÁ”må0
e
3I]
è   ¡ÔÖ ≤î¢§7‘r
```